# A finite extension has a splitting field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I am trying to show that a finite extension $B/F$ has an extension $E/F$ such that $E/F$ is the splitting field of some $f(x)\in F[x]$.

I have trouble seeing where to begin with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Consider $b_1,\dots,b_m$ generators of $B/F$ and $f$ the product of their minimal polynomials.